# What is the location of home page in Magento 2 directory?

Tags: magento2

What is the location of **homepage** in **Magento 2 directory**?

How to edit the **Homepage** section using html code by accessing it **from the directory**?

Comment: what do you want to change in homepage

Comment: I want a registration popup on load of the home page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento Homepage is a **CMS Page** with URL Key **home**.

Homepage layout file is `cms_index_index.xml`

Basically it is a CMS page so you can find `cms_index_index.xml` file in **Magento CMS** module in `vender` folder,

You will get this file but that will not have body and head data, so if need then override in your theme and override and add data.

**How to update Homepage Layout & Content**

**Pt.1 : Go to the Admin Panel of the Magento Store,**

> Navigate to the **Content -> Pages (under Elements) -> Click the Edit
>   on the Homepage.**

Go to the **Content Section** and add your contents, whatever content/data you want to display in homepage,

if you want to add any static block then use this code

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="BLOCK_IDENTIFIER"}}
```

**Note:** `BLOCK_IDENTIFIER = static block which you want to add in homepage.`

**Pt.2 :  Override `cms_index_index.xml` into current working theme :**

Copy the `cms_index_index.xml` from vender magento cms module (`vendor\magento\module-cms\view\frontend\layout\cms_index_index.xml`)

and

paste same to magento cms module in current theme (`app\design\frontend\{NAMESPACE}\{THEME}\Magento_Cms\layout\cms_index_index.xml` )

Then

add static Block

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="BLOCK_CUSTOM_NAME" after="-">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">BLOCK_IDENTIFIER </argument>
       </arguments>
</block>
```

or add Dynamic Block

```
<block class="Company\Module\Block\Index" name="BLOCK_CUSTOM_NAME" template="Company_Module::template.phtml" after="-" />
```

In **Company_Module** module **template.phtml** file you can add your html/php whatever data you want.

or add Containers,

So you will get your respective data in homepage.

Comment: How to add css to that block created in admin panel?

Comment: @kapsid, In Static Block/Page, enable code mode of  the content area by  clicking on **show/hide editor** &  add `<style>/* add you css*/</style>` tag and add css how we do usually. Same way for phtml add style tag and add CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The homepage is a CMS page with identifier `home`. Thus it has no dedicated template. There are various options to use a `phtml`/template file for the homepage. One option would be to add a layout update like (for example):

```
<reference name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
           template="path/to/template.phtml"
           name="custom.homepage"/>
</reference>
```

You also might want to remove the original CMS content for this matter:

```
<referenceBlock name="cms_page" remove="true" />
```

Another approach might be to add blocks to your CMS content like:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="path/to/template.phtml" name="custom.homepage"}}
```

But this could potentially be wrapped inside a paragraph. Well, a lot of different ways to do what you're trying to do, but there is no out-of-the-box template for the homepage.